# Alternatives to iTextSharp for Converting HTML to PDF

Tags: c#, html, pdf, itext

I want to convert an HTML file to PDF using [iTextSharp](http://itextpdf.com/).

I used [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966639/asp-net-php-html-retrieving-html-source-code-from-a-website).

I then did the following to convert it to pdf:

```
HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
htmlWorker.Parse(new StringReader(results));
document.Close();
```

However, none of the CSS is parsed. Any alternatives?

Comment: What have you tried?  The code in that question is retrieving an HTML page, not converting anything to PDF.

Comment: Apologies, edited the question

Comment: `HTMLWorker` is deprecated. try their `XMLWorker` instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

18 months ago, we exhaustibly tested most of the html-to-pdf converters available (paid and free).  In the end, *the hands-down best* html-to-pdf converter was a free, open-source program called [**wkhtmltopdf**](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/).

It is command-line-driven, uses the webkit rendering engine, and accurately (and more importantly, consistently) turns web pages into beautiful looking pdf's.  It also has a variety of useful command-line switches, gives you complete header/footer control, optionally creates table-of-contents pages, and runs very, very fast.  AND -- because it's command line driven, it has the added bonus of easily being used for batch generation.  You simply cannot go wrong.

As a sidenote, this program also has a sister program (bundled in download) called wkhtmltoimage, which works exactly the same way, but converts webpages to a variety of image formats.  This has also been highly useful and we use this functionality for taking snapshots of our web-based tools when building proposals for jobs.

I'm know that I sound like a total fanboy, but I'm not.  I'm simply someone that got so sick-and-tired of all the bullsh*t converters out there that I was doubly blown away when we found wkhtmltopdf.  I simply cannot recommend this little program enough.

Comment: webkit rendering engine ? so how about firefox and IE users ?

Comment: It doesn't matter what web-browser the user has installed on their machine -- as long as the page is coded in semantically correct html, the pdf's will look just fine.

Comment: Wow ! that does sound great !

Comment: Only problem is, is that wkhtmltopdf has to run in a separate process, which means that you lose session information when trying to render views...  Otherwise a good tool

Answer (score 2):

In terms of alternatives I can only recommend [ABCpdf](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm), which we're successfully using to convert large quantities of HTML documents into PDF as part of one of our web applications.

Answer (score 2):

it won't load it automatically. You need to do it manually as follow.

```
 StyleSheet ss = new StyleSheet();
 ss.LoadStyle("body", "leading", "16,0");
 ss.LoadStyle("p", "style", "font-family:Times New Roman");
```

and then you use

```
List<IElement> htmlToPDF = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader("<font face=\"Times\">" + html + "</font>"), style);

foreach (IElement element in htmlToPDF ) {
    document.Add(element);
  }
```

however, only some styles work in itextsharp not all of them.

Actually you should try [XMLWorker](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/xmlworker/), a plugin for itextsharp. It just released this month. It can handle html much better than using only itextsharp.

I think wkhtmltopdf project looks good as well, but I don't know if it will play nice with our production environment since web application is multi-thread program.

Answer (score 1):

Better late then never but here's a pretty good example of how to do it, also explains what is possible and what is not: http://www.thiscouldbeuseful.com/2012/04/itextsharp-to-rescue-converting-html-to.html.

I prefer iTextSharp because imo it provides the most functionality.